# Declaring variable to equal a worksheet name, to reference a table within that sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The task: change the ranges for a sumif across 100+ worksheets.
Each sheet has a uniform naming convention, i.e. "Client_"
Each table within each sheet has the same name as the worksheet. So on "Client_Leaf", there is a table called "Client_Leaf". I keep having an error at the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 line.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
            Sub fixFormulaRanges()

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Dim Client As Worksheet
            Dim ClientTable As ListObject
            Dim varTableName As Variant

            For Each Client In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    With Client
                        If CBool(InStr(1, .Name, "Client_", vbTextCompare)) Then
                            varTblName = .Name
                                Range("f8").Select
                                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                                    "=SUMIF(varTblName & [Sector],RC[-2],varTblName & [Market Value])"

                Range("F8:F20").Select
                Selection.FillDown

                    End If
                End With
             Next Client


            End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

1. The following statements are being run for the *active* worksheet:

   ```
   Range("f8").Select
       ...
   Range("F8:F20").Select
   ```

   If you want it to run for the specific worksheet you're operating on, you'll need to change them to:

   ```
   .Range("f8").Select
       ...
   .Range("F8:F20").Select
   ```
2. You're not properly concatenating your table name into your `SUMIF()` formula.

   Change:

   ```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(varTblName & [Sector],RC[-2],varTblName & [Market Value])"
   ```

   To:

   ```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(" & varTblName & "[Sector],RC[-2]," & varTblName & "[Market Value])"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written,  with the variables enclosed in quotes, vba will treat that as part of a string and will not recognize that you want to use a variable.  Try changing your formula to the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(" & varTblName & "[Sector], RC[-2]," & varTblName & "[Market Value])"
```

Hope that helps!